# Will the fender custom shop build you a guitar with a D-Tuna?

Tags: electric-guitar

I'm considering saving up for my dream guitar. I'm interested in a HSS strat with a Floyd rose trem. What I would also love for my dream guitar to have is a EVH D-Tuna. You can buy this part loose, the EVH company is OK with you adding it to any Floyd rose guitar.

There is some practical requirements. The dtuna needs the Floyd to sit on top of the guitar body and the trem must not recede down into the body of the guitar when you pull up on the Floyd. I don't know enough about Floyd starts to know if this is true for strats by default or if  there would be a need for further mods to get the dtuna working?

Then there is also the issue of whether fender custom shop would do this for you? Is there certain things that are just too blasphemous for the custom shop or is it a case of you bring the cash and they will build it. I'm not certain exactly under what paradigm they operate.

Comment: It seems like this is a question for the Fender Custom Shop itself, or one of its [authorized Showcase Dealers](http://www.fendercustomshop.com/dealers/).

Comment: The only (best) way to get this answered is to direct it at Fender. If yes, you'll also get a quote.

Comment: There are way better, more versatile gutars. Dream on...

Answer (score 2):

The D-tuna doesn't work with the low profile Floyd roses (1000 series), but otherwise is just an add on, so it would work with most of the standard models you can get with the strats, and it is easy to install yourself.

I haven't been a Fender dealer for years, but from what I remember the custom shop is limited to a list of specific stock options, so they probably won't have the D-tuna in stock unless it is part of their product lineup. You can always ask. Either way, when you do your order, let them know that you want to put the D-tuna on and they can tell you which bridges are suitable.

So, if you order a custom Strat with a non low profile Floyd Rose, you could install the D-tuna your self, or have a guitar tech do it for probably a very low price (it's basically unscrewing a screw, and screwing it on in replacement)

EDIT: to back up Tim's comment, for a similar price to the Fender Custom Shop you can find very good guitar builders that will create a truly custom instrument for you. It just depends on if you want the Fender brand on your instrument as part of it.

Comment: Carvin's custom shop looks amazing, FWIW.  And they may incorporate this for you.